# Updating a number from a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
var currentmix = document.getElementById('custommix').value.split(",");
        var additionalprice = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < currentmix.length; i++) {
            if (currentmix[i] != "") {
                var mixinpriceid = "mixinprice"+currentmix[i];
                additionalprice += parseFloat(document.getElementById(mixinpriceid).value));
            }
        }
```

This code is not working :(

I know the expression
`parseFloat(document.getElementById(mixinpriceid).value)`
is giving me the right number on each iteration of the loop

But it is not affecting the variable "additionalprice" outside the for loop.  Any ways to do this???????

Comment: Where are you observing the value to see if it's changed?  Can you add this and the relevant HTML to a runnable code snippet to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: As @David said, please replicate all your code, ideally via runnable snippet

Answer (score 0):

There's a additional parentheses in this statement, please check

```
additionalprice += parseFloat(document.getElementById(mixinpriceid).value));
```

Comment: So simple.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Sathish is correct, you have an extra parenthesis. This snippet will show the code will work without it.

```js
var currentmix = "12345";
var additionalprice = 0;


for (i = 0; i < currentmix.length; i++) {
  if (currentmix[i] != "") {
    var mixinpriceid = "mixinprice" + currentmix[i];
    additionalprice += parseFloat(document.getElementById(mixinpriceid).value);

    console.log(additionalprice);
  }
}

console.log("Final Value: " + additionalprice);
```

```html
<input id="mixinprice1" value="100">mixinprice1</input>
<input id="mixinprice2" value="200">mixinprice2</input>
<input id="mixinprice3" value="300">mixinprice3</input>
<input id="mixinprice4" value="400">mixinprice4</input>
<input id="mixinprice5" value="500">mixinprice5</input>
```